# Matlink reconnections after timeout requiring OpenMATLAB twice

Tags: matlink

My connection from Mathematica to MATLAB using Mathlink seems to timeout after some time of inactivity. In order to reconnect I have to issue these commands:

```
CloseMATLAB[];
OpenMATLAB[];
OpenMATLAB[];
```

I need to issue the `OpenMATLAB` command twice which I find kind of odd. Is this the expected behavior? Is there  an option of sending a heartbeat of something similar to prevent the disconnection?

[image]

On the MATLAB side, I am always issuing the `enableservice('AutomationServer',true)` command. Also, probably because we have a license server, I get this MATLAB message too:

```
Your MATLAB session has timed out.  All license keys have been returned.
```

But it seems to reconnect automatically when I start using it again.

Versions Involved:

- Mathematica 11.3.0
- Windows 10 (version 1709)
- MATLAB R2016a (version 9.0.0.370719)

Comment: This does not sound familiar. It would help to get your OS, Mathematica and MATLAB versions, and preferably steps to reproduce. I won't be able to look at this for about one more week though.

Comment: Can you please respond to my comment above?  I need to know your OS (I assume Windows based on the mention of `enableservice`, but please state it), and Mma/MATLAB versions. Can you come up with steps that consistently reproduce the issue?

Comment: It is Windows 10 and the latest Mathematica. I’ll update the post with more detailed versions later today.

Comment: I don't know how to not reproduce it. It just happens as time goes on. I'll try not using the `enableservice` to see if the problem continues.

Comment: It seems that if you also use the command `DisconnectEngine[]` to close the link, then, you only need to call `OpenMATLAB[]` once.